# Use clean-css compatibility options in grunt-contrib-cssmin

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin, clean-css

I ran into an [issue](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/546) with clean-css in IE10. I'm needing to turn off the spaces after closing braces optimization.

I'm using the grunt-contrib-cssmin plugin to automate all these optimizations, but I don't see a way to access the compatibility flags from within this plugin.

Has anyone been able to target the [compatibility settings](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-set-compatibility-mode) of clean-css from the grunt-contrib-cssmin plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this same issue yesterday, and found the solution here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/issues/192. Basically, if you want to turn that off specifically, try this in the cssmin part of your Gruntfile:

```
options: {
    compatibility: {
        properties: {
            spaceAfterClosingBrace: true
        }
    }
}
```

However, the issue I had was with IE8 not IE10, so I just simply use:

```
options: {
    compatibility: 'ie8'
}
```

Either way, I hope this helps!