# Change "clean css" options in grunt min css

Tags: javascript, css, configuration, grunt-contrib-cssmin, clean-css

Is there some kind of special syntax I need to use to override Clean CSS defaults when using [Grunt CSS min](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)?

Looking at [the docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) I can successfully get the "roundingPrecision" example working but trying to override other Clean CSS rules does not work for me.

I've given a config example below where I'm trying to prevent duplicate rules being removed (in this case I need a non-css variable fallback for browsers that do not support CSS variables). This is not working for me though.

Here is the CSS Min part of my Grunt config:

```
    cssmin: {
        options: {
            removeDuplicateRules: false,
            roundingPrecision: -1
        },
        prod: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                ext: '.min.css',
                src: ['<%= cssPath %>style.css'],
            }]
        },
    },
```

With the above config, this is what happens:

```
    .test {
       background: red;
       background: var(--colour-blue);
    }
```

Becomes

```
    .test{background:var(--colour-blue);}
```

However, the second background rule should **not** be removed.

I've noticed in a another StackOverflow question it seems like I may need to target some specific area of Clean CSS—[Use clean-css compatibility options in grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828059/use-clean-css-compatibility-options-in-grunt-contrib-cssmin)—but I'm not sure how to do that for other properties like "removeDuplicateRules: false".

I'm guessing that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. Any pointers would be helpful—thanks.

## Update #2

As suggested I've tried to use the attempted "level" options as follows, without any success:

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    level: {
      1: {
        all: false
      },
      2: {
        all: false
      }
    }
  },
  prod: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      ext: '.min.css',
      src: ['<%= cssPath %>style.css'],
    }]
  },
},
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate this part? *"...the quotes should **not** be removed..."* Why not? There are no spaces in the name. Please name one browser/version combination that will interpret it differently with/without quotes.

Comment: The example is irrelevant. Clean CSS should do whatever I tell it to do. I've just changed it if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting sassy. Basically, whatever Clean CSS rule I throw at the config, it's not working.

Comment: I apologize. So you're basically saying you've gone over [these](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#use)?

Comment: Might have to do with optimization options being split into `level.1` and `level.2`. [¯\\_(ツ)_/¯](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#level-1-optimizations)

Comment: Yes I thought that too. I tried the following, but no cigar. It fails to suppress any Clean CSS sanitising:


    `cssmin: {
      options: {
        level: {
          1: {
            all: false
          },
          2: {
            all: false
          }
        }
      },
      prod: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          ext: '.min.css',
          src: ['<%= cssPath %>style.css'],
        }]
      },
    },`

Comment: I posted an update to my original question since I couldn't seem to format a code block in a comment

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I've used `grunt` extensively for the past year, but I'm far from what you'd consider an expert at configuring it. Tried to help as much as I could, I'll be here in my corner waiting for you to post the answer when you find it. Fingers crossed, too, of course.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I have used a background property 

`
background: linear-gradient(70deg, #c12365 0%, #c72570 1%, #c12365 calc(0% + 1px), #c12365 40%, #404040 calc(20% + 1px), #404040 75%, #404040 calc(75% + 1px), #404040 100%);
`

when I run the cssmin command it converts it to 

```
background:linear-gradient(70deg, #c12365 0, #c72570 1%, #c12365 calc(0 + 1px), #c12365 40%, #404040 calc(20% + 1px), #404040 75%, #404040 calc(75% + 1px), #404040 100%);
```

Which is a completely different background.

How can I solve this?